# Counting cells with formula that don't return blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

I want to count the number of non-"blank" cells in a column. I have a column of cells with a concatenate() for their corresponding row, i.e.:

```
=CONCATENATE(I10,J10,K10)
=CONCATENATE(I11,J11,K11)
=CONCATENATE(I12,J12,K12)
```

Sometimes these rows are blank, so the concatenate returns "", but there's still a formula there so it's not actually an empty cell, so using :

```
=COUNTIFS(L1:L100,"<>"&"")
```

doesn't exclude the not-really-empty "blanks", and it just returns a count of the full range. Has anyone done anything like this before?
Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNTIF` accepts wild cards.  So to count the non-blank entries in a range, try:

```
=COUNTIF(rngToCount,"?*")
```

All of the salmon colored cells in the screenshot below contain the `CONCATENATE(…` formula:

[image]

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Try to add auxiliary column with formula:

**=IF(AND(ISFORMULA(A1)=TRUE,A1=""),1,0)**

T[image]hen use this formula:

**=COUNT(A1:A6)+COUNTIF(B1:B6,1)**
[image]

Comment: Works well enough as a workaround, thank you. Still curious if it can be done within the COUNTIFS function

Answer (score 0):

You can count all the rows then subtract using COUNTBLANK. The fourth column in the image below has a concatenate function in it.

[image]

```
=COUNTA(F13:F15)-COUNTBLANK(F13:F15)
```